# Wordpress - DIsplay child navigation within child page

Tags: wordpress, parent-child, nav

I currently have a navigation bar displaying all the children of that specific page using the following snippet

```
    <div id="sub_nav_del">
                        <h4>Take a seat</h4>
                        <?php
                        $pages = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=menu_order');
                        $count = 0;
                        foreach($pages as $page)
                        { ?>

                        <ul>
                            <li>
                            <h5 class="del">
                                <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title ?></a>
                            </h5>
                            </li>
                            </ul>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
</div>
```

However I would like the navigation to still be displayed if I am on one of the child pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could determine the post-ID for your `get_pages`-call by asking for a page's parent. If it has no parent, the page's ID will be used.

```
$subnav_parent = ($post->post_parent) ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID;
$pages = get_pages('child_of=' . $subnav_parent . '&sort_column=menu_order');
```

However I can tell you, it won't work for third level pages, but for second level it will be all fine.